# Precedence of dot, cast, new in Java

Tags: java, oop

```
Object o = new String("Hello");
// following won't compile
// myChar = (String)o.charAt(0);
```

However, I can't explain why the following works:

```
char myChar = new String("Hello").charAt(0);
```

It seems that here `new` is getting higher precedence than `.`!

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. `Object` doesn´t have a `charAt` method. 2. Yeah it has in this case, as there wouldn´t be any aviable instance to execute `charAt` on.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object o = new String("Hello");
// following won't compile
// myChar = (String)o.charAt(0);
```

Above will not wrok because Object (o) has no method  `charAt(0)` But above code has one error more , **char can't cast into String** , even Object has a method like `chatAt(0)` like this :

```
(String)o.charAt(0);
```

So use like this, first cast Object into string and call `charAt()`:

```
Object o= new String("Hello");
char myChar = ((String)o).charAt(0);
```

Comment: Your answer should at least include the correction of his first snippet => `Object o = new String("Hello"); char myChar = ((String)o).charAt(0);`

Comment: @AxelH ((String)o).charAt(0); is wrong it will not cast because myChar is char type

Comment: Oh my ... the cast is done on `Object o`, then charAt is called on the cast result ... You should read the operator priority again...